# Add NaN rows in matlab table

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a `Table` which is 100 x 19.

The first 16 columns of Table contains chars, the last 3 columns contain double variables.

How can I insert after the 50th row 3 new rows composed by NaNs so that my table becomes 103 x 19?

Table is in the form

```
Subject Sex Age .... .... ... .. Var1 Var2 Var3
1       M   38                     88 89   99 
2       F   34  ..... .... .. ...  34 34   34
```

and I would like something like (in this example I add only 1 row between the 1st and the 2nd)

```
Subject Sex Age .... .... ... .. Var1 Var2 Var3
1       M   38                     88 89   99 
1       M   38 ..... .... .. . .   NaN NaN NaN
2       F   34  ..... .... .. ...  34 34   34
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create NaN values using the `nan()` function, then append them to your table as new data. You'd need the new data to be a table with the same variable names. I am assuming here that all of them are numeric.

In your case

```
T=[T; array2table(nan(3,8),'variablenames',T.Properties.VariableNames)];
```

Additionally, as per @Dan's comments, it seems you can also do

```
T{51:53,:} = NaN
```

Again, if all values are numeric type.

Comment: Or `T(51:53,:) = NaN`

Comment: @ThomasW. if you're inserting into the middle then `T = [T(1:50,:); nan(3,19); T(51:end,:)]`

Comment: @Dan indeed, i've removed my comment in the mean time :)

Comment: @Dan I get `Right hand side of an assignment into a table must be another table or a cell array.` with your suggestions

Comment: @AnderBiguri if it's an actual table class then use `{}` for the first method and you might have to use you `array2table` for the second (insertion) code

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the data is numeric, then

```
% Create an example table
>> tbl = table((1:100)',(101:200)');
% Append rows
>> tbl{end+1:end+3,:} = nan;
% Move rows
>> tbl{53:end,:} = tbl{50:100,:};
% Insert nans
>> tbl{50:52,:} = nan;
```

If all the data is not numeric then it's a little harder, but the general idea still holds.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The data is mixed. i.e. the first 16 columns are char the rest double

Comment: @gabboshow and how do you want to store NaN in a non numeric variable? It is technically a NaN (not a number) already!

Comment: Ok say that I want to replicate the content of the last non numeric variables and replace the numeric with NaN.

Comment: You can drop the Append rows line if you change the Move rows line to this `tbl{53:end+3,:} = tbl{50:end,:};`. Otherwise this is exactly what I would do.

Comment: @gabboshow but... thats another question. A question quite easily solvavble with the already given info.